# Check server push support

Tags: php, http2, server-push

Is there a possibility to check via php if the server supports the http2 server-push feature?

I'd like to add server push support to a wordpress plugin. But the option should be disabled if the server does not support it. Maybe a JS solution could work as well..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like its not possible to get supported html/2 features. But I found a way to check for http/2. `$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']` always returned `HTTP/1.1`. So its not the savest way. But there is an env called `X_SPDY` which should be `HTTP2` or `QUIC` if the server supports http/2. If its empty, then its http/1(.1).